# storyboard: Two UITabBarController and reusing Views

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I want to reuse a view in another UITabBarController.
Why can't I do this in the storyboard?
The second tabbar only has one view in it and sometimes screws up the first tabbar.

[www.thumbgenius.com/tabbar_reuse.png](http://www.thumbgenius.com/tabbar_reuse.png)

[xcode sample project](http://www.thumbgenius.com/tabbarstoryboardtest.zip)

I've spent about 6 hours trying to figure out to do it this way because I think it's the most intuitive. The sad part is that all I did was duplicate all my views in the storyboard in about 5min and it works fine. But this shouldn't be the way to do it. Now I have to manage all these views, cells, etc twice over.